# iOS simulator screen size issue

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator

This is what i got after updating xcode to 6.3 (simulator 8.3)
Please somebody help me how to solve this?
Each scale size of simulator results the same.

[find the screen shot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MBAl3.png)

Comment: Did you ever solve this this issue? as I'm experiencing the same thing, after what appears to be same issue from the same upgrade.

Comment: @Chris No..i didn't find any technical solution till now but yeah..sometimes it solves this issue automatically,may be after shutting down the system but again it ends up with the same issue after the next the shut down or may in between and this process is still going on !!

Answer (score 0):

[image][image]

at first Create image for Splash as i shown in new image and add it to the project then

select Target:
go to info and then

UILaunchImages~ipad

(as image attached)

then add Splash image detail there.
it will start working fine on every device.

Comment: Thank you first but i could not find UILaunchImages. would you please mind telling me detailed steps..as i am newbie for ios